# How to click on close(X) icon in iframe pop-up in selenium

Tags: selenium

//please check the code below for the close button

```
<div class="fancybox-wrap fancybox-desktop fancybox-type-iframe fancybox-opened" tabindex="-1" style="width: 557px; height: auto; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 396px; opacity: 1; overflow: visible; display: block;">
    <div class="fancybox-skin" style="padding: 0px; width: auto; height: auto;">
    <div class="fancybox-outer">
    <div class="fancybox-inner" style="overflow: auto; width: 557px; height: 385px;">
    <iframe id="fancybox-frame1455168443258" class="fancybox-iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen="" hspace="0" vspace="0" name="fancybox-frame1455168443258" scrolling="auto" src="http://100stohappiness.dev-imaginovation.net/100s-happiness/100s-happiness/login" style="height: 460px;"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <a class="fancybox-item fancybox-close orange-color-bg" href="javascript:;" title="Close"/>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where is HTML code ?

Comment: I edited, it should appear soon

Comment: What code have you tried and what was the result? You should be able to google enough to put something together before asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to switch to the `iframe`

> Java syntax, similar in all languages

```
String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

// switch to the new window
for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    if (!handle.equals(parentHandle))
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    }
}

// click on close button
driver.findElement(By.className("fancybox-close")).click();

// switch back to the old window
driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
```

Comment: I had tried as mentioned but no luck. Actually i am very new to stackoverflow, So can you guys help me how to send the code in body and attach a file any if needed

Comment: @nic.jess Click on edit under your question, you will have window to edit the question. You can add the code there.

Comment: Yes,- org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"fancybox-close"}

Comment: @nic.jess Did you try to switch to the pop up first?

Comment: Yes, I had switched to the pop-up but not able to close. Can u see the screenchot from the link, if not pls tell me how to do it, as i was not able to add image because of not having reputation points

Comment: @nic.jess I couldn't see it. Please post the code as text in **your** question, not my answer.

Comment: i had posted the code, please check it in edited. As i am new to SO i am facing little difficulty in posting effective and informative

Comment: @nic.jess Can you add your Java/C# code for what you are trying to do?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='lgn']")).click();
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.findElement(By.tagName("form"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='frm_login']/div[1]/div/input")).sendKeys("nicolejess246@gmail.com"); 
driver.findElement(By.className("fancybox-close")).click();

Comment: @nic.jess `driver.switchTo().frame(0);` doesn't necessary switch to the pop-up. Try the code in my answer.

Comment: Tried the code you had specified but this time not even able to switch to window, my main concern is about clicking on close button in iframe pop-up not about switching to the pop-up.